# App rejection due to use of CloudKit

Tags: ios, cloudkit, mbaas

I have an app that's been rejected because I test whether the user has access to their CloudKit containers.

If they are not connected, I issue a warning, and tell them to quit the app.

I can't be the only one to experience this.. Any one have a workaround?

Thanks..

For information, the code I'm using to test was sent to me from an Apple TSI engineer. sigh..

Here it is:

```
func isICloudContainerAvailable()->Bool {
    print(#function)
    CKContainer.default().accountStatus { (accountStatus, error) in

        if accountStatus == .available {
            print(#function, "accountStatus 1: ", accountStatus)
            return

        } else {
            print(#function, "accountStatus 2: ", accountStatus)
        }   

        DispatchQueue.global().asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.3) {

            guard error != nil, accountStatus != CKAccountStatus.available else {return}
            print( #function, "accountStatus 3: ", accountStatus)
            print("iCloud account is not available! Be sure you have signed in iCloud on this device!")
        }
    }

    if FileManager.default.ubiquityIdentityToken != nil {
        print("User logged in")
        return true
    }
    else {
        print("User is not logged in")
        return false
    }   
}
```

And the function is used here:

```
if !isICloudContainerAvailable() {

    let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Uh-oh", message: "You must be signed into iCloud \nto use this app.\nPlease quit, log in to iCloud using the 'Settings' app\nand try again", preferredStyle: .alert)

                let defaultAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: nil)
                alertController.addAction(defaultAction)

                self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)

            })
```

Comment: What was the actual rejection message you got?

Comment: This time, I actually got a phone call. The explanation was that I can't force people to log into iCloud. I offered to ask people to log in with their Apple ID, but this too, is unacceptable.

Answer (score 2):

You are not allowed to make you app non functional without CloudKit access. You are only allowed to ask the user to login into iCloud to get the full functionality of the app. It does not matter how (un)functional your app is without CloudKit access. Maybe you could show an instruction screen or some general info about the app. You can then also implement detection of iCloud login and automatically reinitialise your app so that the user does not have to quit (actually kill) and start it again.

Comment: Yea, I am thinking of bolting on a coredata store, but it's a shame. I want people to be able to access their information from any device